# excel automatic formatting, filtering, and obtaining values

Tags: java, excel, shell, scripting

Need to perform the following steps on an excel worksheet automatically without manual intervention. How can I do that?

- There will be columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. Remove three columns C, D and E.
- On Column ‘F’ add ‘Column Name’ with formula =D2/60
- Format Columns C and D to Number/Use 1000 Separator/0 Decimal Places
- Format Column F to Number/Use 1000 Separator/4 Decimal Places
- Filter by src=Total and EventTypes= ~all events~ get Column C value and Column F value - put it in a text file as individual columns
- Filter by src=Total/EventTypes=All get Column C value which is maximum and add it to the columns
- Filter by src=All/EventTypes= ~all events~ get Column C value which is maximum and Column F value which is maximum and add it to the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jexcel http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ is a good package for working with excel sheets.

Comment: I haven't tried filtering but it doesen't look like it. Looks like you will need POI for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can easily do all of this in VBScript, as an Excel macro.
2. You should also be able to do it in any .Net or COM/Active-X aware programming language (e.g. C#, VB6 and Delphi, among many others).
3. If you absolutely need to use Java, you might be able to do it, using a library like Apache POI or OpenXLS:

   - http://poi.apache.org/
   - http://extentech.com/estore/product_detail.jsp?product_group_id=228

Comment: I just remembered that I can do this simply using awk. I just need one help, what exactly happens to a number if I do this "Format Columns C to Number/Use 1000 Separator/0 Decimal Places"? 
and also this "•Format Column F to Number/Use 1000 Separator/4 Decimal Places"
Can you please explain using example?